# I still keep getting the Else statement printing for this grading Java code

Tags: java

For the code below this is just part of what I'm coding. I need help figuring out why it keeps printing out the Else statement only no matter what number I input.

System.out.println("Supply an integer between 1-100 to see if odd or even:");

```
    int number;
    
     number = inputNum.nextInt();
    
    //If statement for finding even or odd numbers
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println(number + " is an even number.");
    } else {
        
        System.out.println(number + " is an odd number.");
    }
    
    // letter grade
    System.out.println("Determine Letter Grade: ");
    
    if(number>=100 && number<90) {
        System.out.print("A");
        
    } 
    
    else if(number>=89 && number<80)
    {
       System.out.print("B");
       
    } 
    else if(number>=79 && number<70)
        
    {
        System.out.print("C");
        
    } 
    else if (number>69 && number<60)
        
    {
        System.out.print("D");
    }
    else  {
        System.out.println("F");
    }
```

Comment: All of your conditions (for the ranges) are impossible. The same number can't be greater than or equal to 100 *and* less than 90, for example.

Comment: Have you actually determined what `number` contains? Use a debugger, or if you must, log the value of `number` to the console. Perhaps it isn't what you expect.

Comment: @JonSkeet - the first is not - I assumed OP couldn't get past the first conditional.

Comment: @RandyCasburn: Ah, sorry - yes, I assume it's actually about the *second* else statement, which will indeed always be printed. I've clarified my first comment.

Answer (score -1):

Check your < and >.  You have them all reversed.
The way you have it written is that not a single input value will ever pass any of those checks.

What you probably meant is:

```
if(number<=100 && number>90) {
    System.out.print("A");
} 
else if(number<=89 && number>80)
{
   System.out.print("B");
} 
else if(number<=79 && number>70)
{
    System.out.print("C");
} 
else if (number<=69 && number>60)   
{
    System.out.print("D");
}
else  {
    System.out.print("F");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The If conditions are always false.

```
number>=100 && number<90
```

This says check if number is greater than 100 and less than 90, which will always result in false. Same for other conditions.

```
if(number <= 100 && number > 90) {
    System.out.print("A");
}
else if(number <= 89 && number > 80) {
   System.out.print("B");     
} 
else if(number <= 79 && number > 70) {
    System.out.print("C");
} 
else if (number <= 69 && number > 60) {
    System.out.print("D");
}
else {
    System.out.println("F");
}
```